# pass jQuery object as function parameter in each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with passing jQuery object as function parameter in `each()` function, but in my function I am not able to use jQuery methods.

```
$('.panel').each(function() {

    $(".row:nth-of-type(2) .input, .row:nth-of-type(3) .input, .row:nth-of-type(4) .input, .row:nth-of-type(5) .input", $(this)).change(function() { 
        getVals($(this).closest('.parent'));
    });
});

function getVals(parent) {
    var fristVal = $('.input', parent)[0].value;
    var secondVal = $('.input', parent)[1].value;

    $('.table-wide', parent)[0].css({ "width": "160px", "height": "160px" });
}
```

I have still this error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].css is not a function
```

Comment: when you say `[0]` it returns s dom element reference which does not have jQuery methods

Comment: `var fristVal = $('.input', parent).val();`

Comment: `$('.table-wide', parent).eq(0).css(..);`

Comment: can we see the associated HTML?

Comment: @ArunPJohny thank you so much! `.eq(0)` fixed this problem!